# My javascript function doesn't seem to be working. I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

My function doesn't seem to be executing correctly. What is wrong? I have already spent 5 hours trying to get this dang function to work. eventually I am going to put links on the photos.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pagenumber=1;
            function increase()
            {
                if(pagenumber == 1)
                {
                return
                }
                pagenumber++;
            }
            function decrease()
            {
                if(pagenumber == 5)
                {
                return
                }
                pagenumber--;
            }
            function slider() {
                if(pagenumber == 1)
                {
                document.getElementById('pg1').style.display='inline';
                document.getElementById('pg2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('down').style.cursor='not-allowed';
                document.getElementById('down').style.background-position='top';

            }
            if(pagenumber == 2)
            {
                document.getElementById('pg1').style.display='h';
                document.getElementById('pg3').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg2').style.display='inline';                  
                document.getElementById('down').style.cursor='pointer';
                document.getElementById('down').style.background-position='bottom';

            }
            if(pagenumber == 3)
            {
                document.getElementById('pg2').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg4').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg3').style.display='inline';
            }
            if(pagenumber == 4)
            {
                document.getElementById('pg3').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg5').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg4').style.display='inline';
                document.getElementById('down').style.cursor='pointer';
                document.getElementById('up').style.background-position='top';

            }
            if(pagenumber == 5)
            {
                document.getElementById('pg4').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('pg5').style.display='inline';
                document.getElementById('up').style.cursor='not-allowed';
                document.getElementById('up').style.background-position='bottom';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body height="183px" bgcolor="#F3F3F3" style="width:279px">
    <div id="down" style="float:left;margin-top:29px;height:27px;width:15px;display:block;cursor:pointer;background:url('website/arrow_left.png') no-repeat top left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top">
        <img src="website/pixel.png" width="15px" height="30px" onclick="decrease()" onclick="slider()">
    </div>
    <div id="up" style="float:right;margin-top:29px;height:27px;width:15px;display:block;cursor:pointer;background:url('website/arrow_right.png') no-repeat top left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top">
        <img src="website/pixel.png" width="15px" height="30px" onclick="increase()" onclick="slider()">
    </div>
    <table style="background:url('website/arrow_middle.png') no-repeat center" align="center">
            <tr id="pg1" style="display:inline">
                <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                    <a href="google.com">
                        <img src="website/oil.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right:25px">
                    <a href="amazon.com">
                        <img src="website/gas.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="pg2" style="display:none">
                <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                    <a href="google.com">
                        <img src="website/nuclear.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right:25px">
                    <a href="amazon.com">
                        <img src="website/solar.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                    </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pg3" style="display:none">
                    <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="google.com">
                            <img src="website/wind.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="amazon.com">
                            <img src="website/hydro.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pg4" style="display:none">
                    <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="google.com">
                            <img src="website/electric.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="amazon.com">
                            <img src="website/thermal.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="pg5" style="display:none">
                    <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="google.com">
                            <img src="website/mining.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right:25px">
                        <a href="amazon.com">
                            <img src="website/transversal.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Just a tip: you're doing `if (x==1) if (x==2) etc`. A better way is to use `if (x==1) else if (x==2) etc` and the best way for that is using [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: You should get a working example going in jsfiddle. Get the links set up and get it working as well as possible here and people will be far more capable of helping you get your issue resolved. I have started one for you here:
 http://jsfiddle.net/loweryaustin/3hTTN/

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign for variables is only used in languages such as PHP. On line 7 take out the dollar sign when you compare the variable in the if and you should be good to go.

```
if($pagenumber == 1)
```

to

```
if(pagenumber == 1)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Also, your elements have 2 different `onclick` attributes set. If you do want an `onclick` to call 2 functions try this:

```
<img src="website/pixel.png" width="15px" height="30px" onclick="increase();slider()">
```

**UPDATE 2:**

To change the `background-position` CSS attribute through JavaScript, the property is called `backgorundPosition`. So try this:

```
document.getElementById('down').style.backgroundPosition = 'bottom';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

This line is the problem:

```
if($pagenumber == 1)
```

change this line to:

```
if(pagenumber == 1)
```

As your variable name is `pagenumber` here:

```
var pagenumber=1;
```

**Problem 2:**

You return immediately after checking `pagenumber == 1` and that's why it never increments. Change your code to:

```
if(pagenumber == 1)
   return ++pagenumber;
```

If you don't want to return value from function then:

```
function increase() {
   if(pagenumber == 1)
       pagenumber++;
}
```

Also make sure to have only one `onclick` event handler in your HTML code.

Comment: I think it'll also get stuck on 1

Comment: @user2557171: You need to learn a bit about Javascript coding to avoid these basic but important mistakes in code.

Comment: the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/xGWp3/1/

## Problem 1

`$pagenumber` must be `pagenumber`

## Problem 2

`pagenumber` can never increase; if it's `1`, which it starts out at, the `increase()` function returns before it can be incremented.

Try rewriting `increase()` and `decrease()` like so:

```
function increase()
{
    if (pagenumber < 5)
    {
        pagenumber++;
    }
}

function decrease()
{
    if (pagenumber > 1)
    {
        pagenumber--;
    }
}
```

## Problem 3

You may also need to change your `onclick` attributes to be of the form `onclick="increase(); slider()"`; I don't think you can have two onclick attributes on a single HTML tag.

## Problem 4

Your functions aren't in the global scope as declared; try declaring them like this:

```
increase = function ()
{
    //...
}
```

## Problem 5

```
document.getElementById('pg1').style.display='h';
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('pg1').style.display='none';
```

With all of these addressed, the code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/xGWp3/1/